# Unable to create a social account with python-social-auth and django-rest-framework when auth token is not in header

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-social-auth

I am using python-social-auth and django-rest-framework to allow users signup with their social accounts in my app.

my case is similar to this post 
[Users are not created after login with facebook (probably an homonymy case)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442307/users-are-not-created-after-login-with-facebook-probably-an-homonymy-case)

I use django-rest-framework's TokenAuthentication to authenticate users

When using my custom user model, when an authtoken is available in the header (user is logged in) the social user account created is linked to the user whose Token is attached to the request as expected, but when there is no token available, it fails to create a new account.

But when using the default django user model, everything works as expected. I suspect that I am not configuring my custom user model properly.

Below is my settings file can you please look and see if you can find out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

#### My settings file

```
 REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    ),
    'PAGINATE_BY': 10
 }

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = os.environ.get('FB_APP_ID')
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = os.environ.get('FB_APP_SECRET')
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']

SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.FLUser'

SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_KEY = os.environ.get('TWITTER_APP_ID')
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_SECRET = os.environ.get('TWITTER_APP_SECRET')

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'social.backends.facebook.Facebook2OAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details'
    # 'apps.users.pipeline.user_details',
)
```

#### Custom Manager

```
class FLUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, username, email, password,
                     is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email,
                          is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
                          is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
                          date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, False, False,
                                 **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, True, True,
                                 **extra_fields)
```

#### Custom User Model

```
class FLUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    GENDER = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name=_('email address'),
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    username = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('username'),
        max_length=30,
        unique=False,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, numbers and '
                    '@/./+/-/_ characters'),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[\w.@+-]+$'),
                                      _('Enter a valid username.'), 'invalid')
        ]
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    birthday = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True,
        default=None,
        null=True
    )
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=GENDER,
        default=None,
        null=True
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='media/avatars',
        blank=True,
        default=None,
        null=True
    )
    sm_avatar = models.URLField(
        blank=True,
        default=None,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=_('Social Media Avatar')
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
         default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.')
    )
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = FLUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username',]

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def get_full_name(self):
        return '''{} {}'''.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    # On Python 3: def __str__(self):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        """
        Sends an email to this User.
        """
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id', 'first_name',)
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')


@receiver(post_save, sender=FLUser)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

#### The View

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
@strategy()
def register_by_access_token(request, backend):
   backend = request.strategy.backend
   if backend.name == 'twitter':
      token = {
          'oauth_token': request.DATA.get('access_token'),
          'oauth_token_secret': os.environ.get('TWITTER_APP_OAUTH_SECRET'),
      }
   elif backend.name == 'facebook':
      token = request.POST.get('access_token')
   else:
      raise Response('Wrong backend type', status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

   user = backend.do_auth(
       access_token=token,
       user=request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user or None
   )
   if user and user.is_active:
      login(request, user)
      user = UserAuthSerializer(user)
      return Response(user.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
   else:
      return Response({'detail': 'Unable to authenticate user'}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Could you share the user manager code too?

Comment: @omab sure, just added it.

Comment: I haven't attended to it in awhile, still unsolved though.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this matters at all, but i think your inheritance is a little wrong for your custom user model (mixins come before):

```
class FLUser(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser):
    ....
```